# How can I connect to mysql from javascript using login path (mylogin.cnf)

Tags: javascript, node-mysql2

I made a windows desktop application using electron. I connected my program to mysql. However, in order to connect to the database, I had to specify the account credentials such as username, password, host, port, and database name. I read through mysql official website concerning security, turns out it is more secure to store these credentials in an encrypted option file (mylogin.cnf). So, I actually did that using  mysql_config_editor and created the file with the necessary credentials.

However, when I try to connect to the database from javascript using that file, it generates an error. Here is the code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');


const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  loginPath: 'mylogin.cnf'
});
function setupDatabase() {
    connection.connect((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error connecting to database:', err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Connected to the database');
    });
    // Additional database setup code...
};
```

it gave me this error:

Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: loginPath. This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration option to a Connection
Error connecting to database: Error: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
at Packet.asError (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Visual Studio\NCDProject\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:728:17)
at ClientHandshake.execute (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Visual Studio\NCDProject\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:29:26)
at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Visual Studio\NCDProject\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:478:34)
at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Visual Studio\NCDProject\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:97:12)
at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Visual Studio\NCDProject\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
at Socket. (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Visual Studio\NCDProject\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:104:25)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
at Socket.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
errno: 1045,
sqlState: '28000',
sqlMessage: "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)",
sql: undefined
}

note: the function setupDatabase() is called when the program is started

I would really appreciate it if someone can help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the documentation for mysql2 suggests that it supports a `loginPath` parameter or encrypted option files.

Don't assume that MySQL's documentation about client programs applies equally to client programs not written by the MySQL team.

Comment: Oh okay, what would be the solution then? I don't want to make my credentials visible in the code for security reasons. Is there another way to use mylogin.cnf to connect to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use eletron-store  and MySQL credntials.